# Getting items form json and pass it as parameter in Blazor wasm

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-webassembly

Hi I've got a problem with my objects in Blazor web assempbly.
I have my component ShipmentsTable where I pass shipments as parameter, but there is a problem because my GetShipmentResult look like this[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
<ShipmentsTable Shipments="@shipments.Items"></ShipmentsTable>

@code {
    private GetShipmentsResult shipments;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    shipments = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<GetShipmentsResult>("https://localhost:5001/api/shipment?page=0");
}

private void NavigateToShipmentForm()
{
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("addShipment");
}
```

}

My GetShipmentResult object

```
public class GetShipmentsResult
    {   
        public List<ShipmentVm> Items { get; set; } = new List<ShipmentVm>();
        public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    }
```

And Json response form Api

```
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "description": "second",
                "expectedTimeOfArrival": "2021-09-10T17:56:24.589",
                "expectedTimeOfDeparture": "2021-09-10T17:56:24.589",
                "actualTimeOfArrival": null,
                "actualTimeOfDeparture": null,
                "isDone": false,
                "placeOfArrivalId": 1,
                "placeOfArrival": null,
                "placeOfDepartureId": 1,
                "placeOfDeparture": null,
                "hash": "tyac2NpISm4t/DjyGhTKnN11EKjsewr5ydNhjrzblMw=",
                "index": 0,
                "prevHash": "LX3OqOZpt88fvTIQfoiLs0zzoEbNBMCMdV1QsqNVRRk=",
                "timeStamp": "2021-09-23T11:52:51.8174364"
            }
            ],
"totalCount" : 1
}

public class ShipmentVm
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpectedTimeOfArrival { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpectedTimeOfDeparture { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ActualTimeOfArrival { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ActualTimeOfDeparture { get; set; }
        public bool IsDone { get; set; }
        public int PlaceOfArrivalId { get; set; }
        public int PlaceOfDepartureId { get; set; }
        public byte[] Hash { get; set; }
        public byte[] PrevHash { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }
```

blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.UpdateRetainedChildComponent(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldComponentIndex, Int32 newComponentIndex)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()

```
@using TrakkerWASM.Client.Models
@using TrakkerWASM.Client.Models.TestVm
<h3>Shipments table</h3>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Is done</th>
            <th>Time stamp</th>
            <th>Hash</th>
            <th>Previous hash</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var shipment in Shipments)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@shipment.IsDone</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@shipment.TimeStamp</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@shipment.Hash.ToString()</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@shipment.PrevHash</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<ShipmentVm> Shipments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post ShipmentVm class too, pls?

Comment: @Serge Yes, please. Do you want also blazor error form browser console?

Comment: What is the question? That screenshot shows nothing strange. The `GetShipmentsResult.Items` property contains a single  `ShipmentVm` item

Comment: @Kamil Thanks, It would be nice if you post an error too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my question is why when I pass as a parameter shipment.Items to ShipmentsTable Component I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: That's not what you posted. You didn't post any error message or exception. Post the actual full exception text as *text*, not unreadable images

Comment: The error complains about rendering in the `ShipmentsTable` component. There's no code from that component though so it's impossible to even guess what may be wrong

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added my ShipmentsTable, if this change sth?

Answer (score 1):

GetFromJsonAsync sometimes gives an weird result. Try to use Newtonsoft.Json and maybe you will see the difference. I am usually using an algorithm like this

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:5001/api/shipment?page=0");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        shipments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetShipmentsResult>(stringData);
    }
 
}
```

also you have to change you VM since deserializer doesnt recognize byte[]

```
public string Hash { get; set; }
 public string PrevHash { get; set; }
```

or maybe you need something like this

```
[JsonProperty("hash")]
public string HashString { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("prevHash")]
public string PrevHashString { get; set; }

public byte[] Hash { 
get { return Convert.FromBase64String(HashString);} 
set { HashString=  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(value, 0, value.Length); }
}
public byte[] PrevHash { 
get { return Convert.FromBase64String(PrevHashString);} 
set { PrevHashString=  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(value, 0, value.Length); } 
}
```